# Mathematica syntax with combined Prefix and Times operator: @*

Tags: syntax

In a post on the Mathematica Community, Anton Antonov uses a syntax that I have never seen.  It is the prefix function @ combined with the Times operator *.  The combination appears to bind the command prefixed by the @ sign to the following command, such that the two commands are applied together to an expression.  The example is:

```
titanicData = Flatten@*List@@@ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "Titanic"}, "Data"];
```

What I see happening here is that the List command is applied at Level 1 of the List, that is to the first Rule:

```
{"1st", 29., "female"} -> "survived"
```

and converts it from a Rule to a nested List

```
{{"1st", 29., "female"}, "survived"}
```

and then the Flatten command is applied "immediately" to this Level 1 List in order to remove the nesting:

```
{"1st", 29., "female", "survived"}
```

And then this "combined command" (bound by the precedence of the Times operator?) is applied to each Level 1 expression in the example data list (as is expected by the @@@ Apply syntax).

So, I have three questions:

1. Is my summary above intelligible?
2. How would this be better stated?
3. Where is this documented?

Unfortunately, there is one further question:

1. Is this just obvious to everyone and I am having a brain fart?

Thank you in advance for some enlightenment

Comment: Use the help facility for "Composition"

Comment: See [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) and search for `@*`.

Comment: The summary is correct. Towards the 4-th question: The answer is "yes". ;p

Comment: That notation has been added sometime after MMA 9.0. I didn't know it existed. Upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

See [**Composition (@*)**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html).

Since asterisk is also a wildcard character, it is difficult to find in a direct search.

In your example, `Flatten @* List` is the composition of the functions `Flatten` and `List`.

Comment: +1, but I don't think wildcards work for documentation search (also: for Mathematica, `@` is also a wildcard character).  I am not convinced that the doc centre couldn't be made to yield reasonable results when searching for `@*`.

Comment: @Szabolcs The documentation centre appears to use the "standard" `*` wildcard but nothing else. Searching `fibon*` and `fibon` yields 103 and 0 results respectively [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ydj3.png). The problem appears to be unique to `@*`. Note `@@` is able to bring up `Apply` while `@*` does not yield `Composition` [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlw3l.png). Also `*` alone is able to bring up `Times`, but `* a` returns an InputForm cell [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xgMb.png)! Does this strange behaviour merit a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Say you want a function `snd` that emits the piano sound of the note `n`. Here is how you can define it:

```
snd=EmitSound@*Sound@*SoundNote
```

`snd@n` will work as expected.
Without the double use of `@*` you will get errors in the definition of the function or you will not get the expected output. Without `Composition` you need a less concise syntax that uses pure functions (`# &`) or `snd[n_]:=` etc.